# Equivalent to pread/pwrite in MSVC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, posix

What calls best emulate [pread/pwrite](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man2/pwrite.2.html) in MSVC 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the C runtime library level, look at [fread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kt0etdcs%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), [fwrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h9t88zwz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [fseek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/75yw9bf3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

At the Win32 API level, have a look at [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and [SetFilePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  MSDN has extensive coverage of [file I/O API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Note that both ReadFile and WriteFile take an [OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) struct argument, which lets you specify a file offset.  The offset is respected for all files that support byte offsets, even when opened for synchronous (i.e. non 'overlapped') I/O.

Depending on the problem you are trying to solve, [file mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) may be a better design choice.

Comment: With the exception of file mapping, these calls are not atomic with respect to file position. I think file mapping is a little far afield, but it's a consideration.

Comment: ReadFile/WriteFile take an OVERLAPPED argument, which lets you specify the file offset you're interested in.  Don't let the OVERLAPPED type name mislead you -- the offset is respected even for files opened for synchronous I/O.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just use the **lpOverlapped** parameter to [**ReadFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[**WriteFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pass a pointer to an [**OVERLAPPED**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure with the offset specified in **Offset** and **OffsetHigh**.

(Note: You don't actually get overlapping IO unless the handle was opened with **FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED**.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Oren seems correct but doesn't seem to meet the needs. Actually, I too was here for searching the answer but couldn't find it. So, I will update a bit here.

As said,

At the C runtime library level, there are [fread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kt0etdcs(v=VS.80).aspx), [fwrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h9t88zwz(v=VS.80).aspx) and [fseek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/75yw9bf3(v=VS.80).aspx).

At the Win32 API level, we can have two level of abstractions. One at the lower level which works with **file descriptors** and other at higher level which works with Windows' defined data structures such as **File and Handle**.

If you wish to work with Files and Handles, you have [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(v=VS.85).aspx), [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747(v=VS.85).aspx), and [SetFilePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541(v=VS.85).aspx). But most the time, C++ developers prefer working with File Descriptors. For that, you have [_read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/read?view=vs-2019), [_write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/write?view=vs-2019) and [_lseek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/lseek-lseeki64?view=vs-2019).